# first argument must be callable or None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, collections

I want to group Countries in the following dictionary by continent:

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
```

However, when I try:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Could anyone give a helping hand?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `list`? Then you have overwritten the `list` function…

Comment: @Błotosmętek thanks so much I've sorted it out now!

Comment: I dont have variable named `list`, but first time code run correctly. After first run, it gives above said error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing this error:
`TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`,

**because you have somewhere in your code a variable stored by the name `list`.**

You need to remove that:

```
del list
```

Then do the below. It should work:

```
In [512]: dictionary = defaultdict(list) 
     ...: for key, value in ContinentDict.items(): 
     ...:     dictionary[value].append(key) 

In [513]: dictionary                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[513]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'Asia': ['China', 'Japan', 'India', 'South Korea', 'Iran'],
             'North America': ['United States', 'Canada'],
             'Europe': ['United Kingdom',
              'Russian Federation',
              'Germany',
              'France',
              'Italy',
              'Spain'],
             'Australia': ['Australia'],
             'South America': ['Brazil']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas you can create a dataframe, groupby your continents and then create a dictionary.

```
group_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ContinentDict,orient='index')\
                   .reset_index().groupby(0).agg(list)['index'].to_dict()

print(group_dict)

{'Asia': ['China', 'Japan', 'India', 'South Korea', 'Iran'],
 'Australia': ['Australia'],
 'Europe': ['United Kingdom',
  'Russian Federation',
  'Germany',
  'France',
  'Italy',
  'Spain'],
 'North America': ['United States', 'Canada'],
 'South America': ['Brazil']}
```